# ANTLR4 - mismatched input '<EOF>'

Tags: input, antlr4, eof, mismatch

I'm trying to edit Java's grammar in ANTLR that uses '\n' instead of ';' as the STMTEND, but the semicolon is still optional. However, I'm encountering this error from my parser even though I've already put an explicit EOF at the end of the starting rule of the grammar. It keeps on showing me this error:

```
mismatched input '<EOF>' expecting {',', '
'}
```

This is the starting grammar:

```
grammar Baraco;

// starting point for parsing a java file
compilationUnit
:   constDeclaration* methodDeclaration* statement* EOF
;
```

This is the version of STMTEND I created along with the fragment NEWLINE:

```
STMTEND     : SEMI NEWLINE*
            | NEWLINE
            ;

fragment
NEWLINE
:   '\r' '\n'
|   '\n'
|   '\r'
;
```

Lastly, this is the input I have been entering to my parser just to test:

```
int x = 0
```

Comment: Where did you take the Java grammar ? The `compilationUnit ` in [this one](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/java/Java.g4) is different.

Comment: ... and in which parser rule do you insert the `STMTEND` lexer rule ?